# Convert MP3 to MIDI in C#

Tags: c#, mp3, midi, converters

I'm working on a program (C#) to convert an MP3 file to MIDI, but I have a problem with converting it. How should I do?
Is there any library to generate MIDI from MP3 file 
Thank You

Comment: Start by __understanding__ those formats. Then try something easier. Seriously, you would need to do a fourier analysis and work from there. Tough stuff..

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advice, but i want to make an app like synthesia, but i confused, could you give some advice what format sound (MP3,MIDI,WAV) can use to program on computer ? sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not a converter. It seems that you need some complicated process to generate a MIDI from an MP3 file. There are some useful discussions in the following links:

- https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/992205/How-do-I-convert-an-mp-wav-file-to-midi-in-vb-net
- https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/505842-writing-a-module-to-convert-mp3-to-midi-files/

Comment: Okee, thanks but is have to use MIDI format to programming sound on computer (like synthesia) because i make a app like synthesia ? or WAV format file can use to program ? Sorry for my english